# Jquery - how to change css based on HTML5 color picker without using DOM id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a somewhat more generalisable function than `$("#id").click(function(){ //change css });`. Concretely, let's say I have this jquery that tries to change the background-color of divs ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p8fw68to/)):

```
<div class="swatch" id="swatch1"></div>
<div class="swatch" id="swatch2"></div>
<div class="swatch" id="swatch3"></div>
<input type="color" id="picker">

<script>
$(".swatch").click(function(){
//I want this function to fire whenever I click on a .swatch class div
    $("#picker").trigger("click");
});
$("#picker").change(function(){
    //would be great to be able to select the div I clicked on
    //without explicitly selecting it by hard-coded ID
    $("#swatchID").css("background-color",$("#picker").val());
});
</script>
```

Clearly I don't want to write separate functions for each div, but I believe that `$(this)` will change scope from the div to the input if I try to embed `$("#picker").change(...)` inside `$(".swatch").click(...)`, right? How to I create a generalizable function that can recognise which div I clicked on and change its css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save (this) by adding property

```js
$(".swatch").click(function(){
   
  $("#picker").get(0).savedContainer=this
    $("#picker").trigger("click");
});
$("#picker").change(function(){

  if(this.savedContainer){
    $(this.savedContainer).css("background-color",$("#picker").val());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swatch" id="swatch1">1111111111</div>
<div class="swatch" id="swatch2">2222222222</div>
<div class="swatch" id="swatch3">3333333333</div>
<input type="color" id="picker">
```

by property

Comment: This works, and doesn't select multiple divs for multiple clicks. Could you explain about why the input element's `.savedContainer` property is the div I clicked on? I can't find any reference to this property online. And then why do you set it to `= this` (i.e. the window), but then use `this.savedContainer` as the div in the second function?

Comment: Ooooh, I get it (I completely misinterpreted the scope of `this`). You assign the DOM element a custom property called `.savedContainer`, and you assign it the DOM object representing the clicked-upon div. You then access this object via the `#picker.savedContainer` property when assigning  the `.css(...)`. This way you avoid having multple selector functions waiting for updates when the `<input>` changes.

Answer (score 2):

Just save whatever Container was clicked in a variable like this:

```
<div class="swatch" id="swatch1"></div>
<div class="swatch" id="swatch2"></div>
<div class="swatch" id="swatch3"></div>
<input type="color" id="picker">

<script>
var savedContainer;
$(".swatch").click(function(){
    savedContainer = $(this);
    $("#picker").trigger("click");
});
$("#picker").change(function(){
    savedContainer.css("background-color",$("#picker").val());
});
</script>
```

Here is a second attempt, that fires the "change" eventhandler only once per click on a `.swatch` container. If your Colorpick autocloses after a selection this might work for you.

```
$(".swatch").click(function(){

    var clickedContainer = $(this);
    $("#picker").trigger("click");

    $("#picker").one('change', function(){
        clickedContainer.css("background-color",$("#picker").val());
    });

});
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Is there a way to do it without saving `$(this)` to a global variable each eligible click?

Comment: I dont think so, unless your Colorpicker has some kind auf callback function that gets triggered on selection, that you can update everytime your div containers get clicked.

Comment: I updated my answer with a different approach. that might work for your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you do multiple click+cancel operations, multiple divs' background-color are changed at once. I was thinking that `clickedContainer.last().css(...)` should work, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: OK, so a `console.log(clickedContainer)` seems to indicate that the `$("#picker").one(...)` functions "accumulate" for multiple clicks even if the picker is cancelled. I don't believe that the `<input>` returns a value if it is cancelled without changing, making this hard to detect.